# what layer would you implement a Java web service

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, web-applications

I was asked this in my interview today, I applied for a graduate developer role, I was asked

in an Java ee application which is distributed across multiple layers namely :

```
Web/Presentation layer 
Business layer
integration layer
database layer
```

in which of these layers would a web service most likely to be implemented

(there wasn't enough detail given I was straight asked this question)

I have searched all over but couldn't find a answer

Comment: I think a better question to ask is: what _aspects_ of a web service are distributed across which layers? The rote definition of a "web service" transcends all of these descriptions, depending on what segment of the code you're talking about. Good luck with your interview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, not the web/presentation layer; I would say the business layer. That way multiple clients can communicate with it by using those web services.

Answer (score 2):

It kind of depends.  I would lean towards the business layer because a web service is typically associated with a core functionality of your system.  However, it is also possible for it to be in the integration layer (which I am assuming means things like DAOs, file transfer objects, etc).  If it is an "internal web service" it could go here as well as a pseudo-broker of information.  I would not put it in the database tier or the presentation tier, because those two things have nothing to do with web services.  Asking about the web tier, was a way to trick up candidates that did not have a thorough understanding of MVC / web development frameworks.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion it should be on the Business layer for most cases (providing a specific high level service, hiding all the inner working). Maybe you can consider to implement it in the Integration layer but that would depend on the purpose of the service.

Answer (score -1):

The business layer separates the business logic from other modules, such as the data access layer (DAL) and user interface (UI).  While the WS could implement business logic it could also be considered p/o the interface layer

Answer (score -1):

Alwase note in mind every project have a four layer
1). Fronted layer/controller layer (2). Business Delegation layer (3). Service Layer (4). DAO Layer
summary :- we are always going to develop a project first writing client interaction page using the jsp and end user place data in jsp then data will be going to handle by servlet after that calling the value object(VO) i.e java bean class for set the data into Business layer using Business Object after that Business layer will be call the pojo class i.e nothing but service layer that layer responsible for the call the DAO layer for persist the data into persistence software(Back-end),so be careful in project development always  service layer will going to expose the services to the external web tier not any other layer.